# nodejs mongoose push to an array inside schema

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoose schema `inbox-model`:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    data: [{
        from: String,
        to: String,
        msg: String
    }]
})

var Inbox = module.exports = mongoose.model('Inbox',schema);

module.exports.addData = function(inbox, callBack){
    inbox.save(callBack);
}
```

I need to add to `data[]` array for a specific email when there's new data for that email address.

I can add data this way, through my router by calling:

```
var Inbox = require('inbox-model');

var inbox = new Inbox({
    email: 'some@email.com',
    data:[{
       from: 'from',
       to: 'to',
       msg: 'msg'
})

Inbox.addData(inbox, Inbox);
```

though it doesn't add to `data[]` but keeps adding a whole `row`.

Help is much appreciated, I've searched for similar questions, but I couldn't find on adding data, just creating models with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered a lot of time on StackOverflow. However, I'm answering it again

```js
// Schema File - userSchema.js
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  data: [{
        from: String,
        to: String,
        msg: String
  }]
})

const user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)

module.exports = user

// Service File

const user = require('./userSchema')

function someFunction(email, from, to, message) {
  user.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, document) {
    if (document) {
      
      document.data.push({
        from: from,
        to: to,
        msg: message
      })
      
      document.save(function(err) {
        err != null ? console.log(err) : console.log('Data updated')
      })
      
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: `document` is null, any idea why?

Comment: It's null because the document you're looking for using the email ID doesn't exist on the DB. Please verify

Comment: Just tried that too, thank you it works!

Comment: Good that it worked :)

Comment: If it has been answered before, flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: You should read the duplicate too. There is a reason why we point people to the existing answers rather than post new ones. A primary reason is they stand more chance of actually giving the correct information. You don't "retrieve the document from the server, modify it and save it back" as good practice in working with a database, and you should understand why. It will make the code you are working on so much better. Go and learn please.